# What's the value of $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{3x^2y^6}{(x^3+y^3)^2}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to know the value of the next limit (and prove it) or if it does not exist

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{3x^2y^6}{(x^3+y^3)^2}$

to find if

$ f(x,y)=  \dfrac{x^3y^3}{x^3+y^3}$ if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ or

$f(x,y)=0 $ if $(x,y)=(0,0)$

is differentiable in $(0,0)$. This because I was thinking to use the theorem that says that if a function has continuous first partial derivates in a region surrounding the point, then this function is differentiable in that point.

But if you know how to prove that $f(x,y)$ is differentiable or not in another way, I ask you to teach me.

Thanks

Comment: This function is undefined on the line $y=-x$.

Comment: Yes, but that does not work to prove that the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the limit is approached along the curve described parametrically by $x=t$, $y^3=-t^3+t^n$, then we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{3x^2y^6}{(x^3+y^3)^2}&=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{3t^2(-t^3+t^n)^2}{t^{2n}}\\\\
&=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{3\left(t^8+t^{2n+2}-2t^{5+n}\right)}{t^{2n}} \tag 1
\end{align}$$

The limit on the right-hand side of $(1)$ depends on $n$; for $n=3$ the limit is $0$, for $n=5$ the limit is $\infty$.  Inasmuch as the value for the limit of interest depends on the path, the limit does not exist.